Why is my Ni or Fe cathode blackening and pores getting blocked during alkaline (6 M KOH) electrolysis?
I am conducting an electrolysis process for hydrogen $(\ce{H2})$ and oxygen $(\ce{O2})$ generation using a $\pu{6 M}$ $\ce{KOH}$ alkaline solution.
During the process, I have observed that my cathode becomes blackened, and the pores in the electrode get blocked.
Here are the specifics of my setup:

I am using porous nickel electrodes and stainless steel (SS) electrodes in different experiments. Both types of electrodes are experiencing the same issue: blackening and pore blockage.
My electrolyte solution doesn't have any impurities.
The balance of plant (BOP; rest of the parts in the setup) components made of SS316 have been passivated.

Despite these measures, I am unable to determine the cause of the cathode blackening and pore blockage.

Could anyone provide insights into why this might be happening and suggest potential solutions to prevent it?


Have you tried other cathode materials, to be sure the electrolyte is not the issue? Do you use any diaphragm or salt bridge? As it could be anodic material deposited on the cathode.

There can be many causes. Nickel and steel are not inert to strongly alkaline solutions. Have you done control experiments? Just soak the a new electrode in 6 M KOH for a day and do not pass current. What happens? Does it remain intact or becomes black? You have to study the metal properties esp. from descriptive inorganic chemistry books, especially base corrosion of given metals, before conducting fancy electrochemical experiments.

I have tried multiple controlled experiments. Cathode always gets black color deposition. In presence of SS (SS316) tubing/piping in auxiliary system this effect get accelerated. Even after passivating SS316 tubing/piping.

You missed my point. Did you just let the a new nickel electrode sit in KOH for a day? No current should be passed during this test and no electrical connections should be made! This is the control experiment I am talking about. Does that become black?

Without electrolysis , without electrical connection I am not seeing any change in cathode color

You state that the pores in the electrode are blocked. What does it mean ? Do you use electrodes covered by porous substances ? Why ? How can you be sure that these pores are blocked ? How do you "unblock" these pores ? Is there any connection between the blackening and the pores being blocked ?

In typical KOH solutions there's some iron contamination and even SS316 can leak some iron. Iron can then (electro)deposit inside the pores, this is a typical issue for alkaline electrolyzers. Try monitoring how much Fe contamination you have.

I assumed you are involving in industrial scale $\ce{H2}$ production. According to the Ref.1:

$\ce{H2}$-evolution catalysts based on high surface area $\ce{Ni}$ electrodes in alkaline media are low-cost alternatives that are better suited for large-scale $\ce{H2}$ generation. A problem these electrodes face is that the hydrogen evolution reaction (HER) activity of $\ce{Ni}$ cathodes is significantly greater on fresh electrodes than after several hours of electrolysis.

I assume that you are experiencing that same fact during your electrolysis experiment. This gradual decrease of the HER activity with time has been previously suggested to arise from the formation of a nickel hydride on surface or bulk phase, for example, Ref.2. The abstract of Ref.1 explains further facts:

$\ce{Ni}$-based catalysts in aqueous alkaline media are low-cost electrode materials for electrolytic hydrogen generation, a renewable method of producing fuel and industrial feedstock. However, $\ce{Ni}$ cathodes show a significant decrease in their hydrogen evolution reaction (HER) activity after several hours of electrolysis. Further, industrial electrolysers are often subjected to transient anodic currents, the effects of which on $\ce{Ni}$-based catalysts are not well-known. We consider the source of electrode deactivation and the effects of temporary anodic currents on smooth metallic $\ce{Ni}$ electrodes in alkaline solutions by cyclic voltammetry (CV), galvanostatic and potentiostatic polarization, X-ray diffraction (XRD) and X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy (XPS). Polished surfaces are covered by a bilayer composed of $\ce{\alpha-Ni(OH)2}$ underlaid by non-stoichiometric NiOx. Below the reversible hydrogen electrode (RHE) potential, the air-formed layer mostly reduces to $\ce{Ni}$ metal and H atoms incorporate deep into the electrode material. Under industrial conditions, i.e., concentrated NaOH/KOH solutions and large cathodic current densities, $\ce{\alpha-NiH_x}$ and $\ce{\beta-NiH_x}$ can form at the electrode surface. Above the RHE potential, NiOx, $\ce{\alpha-Ni(OH)2}$, $\ce{\beta-Ni(OH)2}$ and $\ce{\beta-NiOOH}$ form reversibly and mostly reduce back to $\ce{Ni}$ on subsequent cathodic polarization. However, repeated oxidation and reduction will introduce strain on a catalyst material, which may lead to its mechanical failure.

Reversible electrode potentials for above processes discussed in their study are given as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{#} &\text{Half reaction} & \text{Potential }  V_\mathrm{RHE} & \text{Comments}\\\hline
1 & \ce{Ni_{(s)} + xH2O_{(l)} + x e- <=> \beta-NiH_x_{(s)} + xOH-_{(aq)}} & -0.12-\pu{-0.13 V} & x =0.6-0.65\\
2 & \ce{Ni_{(s)} + xH2O_{(l)} + x e- <=> \alpha-NiH_x_{(s)} + xOH-_{(aq)}} & -0.075-\pu{-0.095 V} & x =0.01-0.02\\
3 & \ce{H2O_{(l)} + 2 e- <=> 2OH-_{(aq)} + H2_{(g)}} & \pu{0.00 V} & -\\
4 & \ce{\beta-Ni(OH)2_{(s)} + 2 e- <=> Ni_{(s)} + 2OH-_{(aq)}} & \pu{0.108 V} & \text{Ref.3}\\
5 & \ce{NiO_{(s)} + H2O_{(l)} + 2 e- <=> Ni_{(s)} + 2OH-_{(aq)}} & \pu{0.132 V} & -\\
6 & \ce{O2_{(g)} + 2H2O_{(l)} + 4 e- <=> 4OH-_{(aq)}} & \pu{1.229 V} &  -\\
7 & \ce{\beta-NiOOH_{(s)} + H2O_{(l)} + e- <=> \beta-Ni(OH)2_{(s)} + OH-_{(aq)}} & 1.37-\pu{1.40 V} &  \text{Ref.4}\\
\end{array}
$$
These measurements are determined using concentrations of $\ce{KOH}$ up to 30%, which come close to $\pu{5-6 M}$ solutions (close enough to OP's concentrations). Therefore, it is safe to assume that at least your $\ce{Ni}$ electrode may undergo electrochemical reaction as described in detail in Ref.1 (related half reactions are shown in above table). For example, hydrogen adsorption onto the $\ce{Ni}$-surface (entries $1$ and $2$) is related to hydrogen adsorption in $\ce{Pd}$-surface during hydrogenation (recall Raney $\ce{Ni}$). Ref.5 shows a nice schematic diagram for one of these "side" reactions:

Moreover, according to Wikipedia, solid $\ce{Ni(OH)2}$ is green but $\ce{NiOOH}$ is black in color.
In different aspect, $\ce{Fe}$ and $\ce{Ni}$ concentrations in $\ce{KOH}$ electrolytes from different manufacturers vary significantly. Even ultrahigh purity (UHP) $\ce{KOH}$ is not entirely free from $\ce{Fe}$ $(∼\pu{18 ppb})$ according to Ref.5.
Note: Electrode potentials are also studied for nickel hydroxide batteries for range of $\ce{KOH}$ concentrations Ref.6). Hydrogen and oxygen evolution in alkaline water by  electrolysis using nickel hydroxide is also known (Ref.7).

References:

David S. Hall, Christina Bock4, and Barry R. MacDougall, "The Electrochemistry of Metallic Nickel: Oxides, Hydroxides, Hydrides and Alkaline Hydrogen Evolution," Journal of The Electrochemical Society 2013, 160(3),  F235-F243 (DOI: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/2.026303jes)(PDF).
Michele Bernardini, Nicola Comisso, Giuliano Mengoli, and Livio Sinico, "Formation of nickel hydrides by hydrogen evolution in alkaline media: effect of temperature," Journal of Electroanalytical Chemistry 1998, 457(1-2), 205-219 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0728(98)00307-6).
According to Ref 1 footnote, the measurement, $\pu{0.108 V}$ predates the discovery of $\ce{\alpha-Ni(OH)2_{(s)}}$ on nickel oxide electrode in 1966: H. Bode, K. Dehmelt, J. Witte, "Zur kenntnis der nickelhydroxidelektrode—I.Über das nickel (II)-hydroxidhydrat," Electrochim. Acta 1966, 11(8), 1079-1084 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0013-4686(66)80045-2).
Also according to another Ref 1 footnote, the exact potential or its range range depends on the structural order of the electrode material.
Raúl A. Márquez, Kenta Kawashima, Yoon Jun Son, Grace Castelino, Nathaniel Miller, Lettie A. Smith, Chikaodili E. Chukwuneke, and C. Buddie Mullins, "Getting the Basics Right: Preparing Alkaline Electrolytes for Electrochemical Applications," ACS Energy Lett. 2023, 8(2), 1141–1146 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/acsenergylett.2c02847).
R. Barnard, C. F. Randell, and F. L. Tye, "Studies concerning charged nickel hydroxide electrodes I. Measurement of reversible potentials," Journal of Applied Electrochemistry 1980, 10(1), 109–125 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00937345).
Long Chen, Xiaoli Dong, Yonggang Wang, and Yongyao Xia, "Separating hydrogen and oxygen evolution in alkaline water electrolysis using nickel hydroxide," Nature Communications 2016, 7(1), Article number: 11741 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1038/ncomms11741).

